# Why does Hyper-V virtual network not pass through bittorrent traffic on the host machine?

Tags: networking, bittorrent, hyper-v

I installed Hyper-V on my dev machine and I created an Android phone emulator and also a virtual machine. During creation of the Android phone emulator, Hyper-V created virtual switch automatically.

Everything seemed to work fine, I have internet connection, Skype and web browsing works. But when I wanted to download Ubuntu for my VM, I noticed that qBittorrent shows yellow icon and says "No direct connections" and it dies while trying to get torrent info from http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce with `Not working` message.

I had to go to my network settings, disable the `vEthernet (Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Virtual Switch)` connection and turn off the `Hyper-V extensible virtual switch` feature on my real Ethernet connection, and then all the other checkboxes get turned on automatically. After that, qBittorrent starts working again.

What is wrong with Hyper-V vEthernet connection and how to configure it to work with all kinds of network traffic including qBittorrent? I don't want to go through all this disabling/enabling process each time I want to run VMs or torrents or whatnot.

Comment: Does it do this will any other BT client?

Comment: I did not try yet. But it seems I found a temporary fix: http://i.imgur.com/iir5wmP.png I have to make sure qBittorent is listening to the new vEthernet switch instead of the real Ethernet connection. Not sure, if this is the best way, though.

Comment: I think you found the problem.

Comment: Yes, this might be it. Now I have read some articles about Hyper-V switch and understood that it works completely other way than I imagined, and that my physical network adapter is no more the "real" network gateway. It's so complicated with Hyper-V; VirtualBox somehow manages to get everything working without messing up network in some almost sick ways.